# Group of prime with identity two possible?

Tags: group-theory

Is there any operation that makes a set of primes i.e. {2,3,5,7.... .} a group with identity 2?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Ok I will take care to provide all necessary info regarding  the question, next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret your question.

1. If you want the group to be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual addition then no. To see this, all we need to see is that $3$ has no inverse.
2. If you just want the group to have as its underlying set the set of all primes, then yes. Since there are countably infinitely many primes, there is a bijection between the set of all primes and the set of integers, say $f$ where $f(2)=0$. Then we can define multiplication of two primes $a$ and $b$ by $$a\ast b=f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b))$$ it isn't hard to prove this will be a group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ with the thing represented by the symbol $2$ as the identity.

Comment: Specifically, the "obvious" $f$ is where $f(p)$ is the number of primes less than $p$.

Comment: @SteveJessop maybe it isn't so obvious considering that your proposal for $f$ actually gives a bijection between the primes and the natural numbers, not the primes and the integers.

Comment: Good point, well made. Sticklers are demanding that groups actually come equipped with inverses now, are they? So it actually has to map to something like half that value if that value's even, and minus half the value if it's odd (round away from zero). Anyway I just meant to indicate that there should be no mystery about this bijection. It's not some high-falutin' existence theorem, we can write one down without too much trouble (and ideally less trouble than I had).

Comment: @SteveJessop another common sense way to get the bijection would be to just compose your proposed bijection with the canonical bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ given by the ordering $(0,1,-1,2,-2,...)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If I consider the set {2,3,5} then applying operation given above on 3 nd 5 then 3*5=7 which is not the element of the set . Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: @user306288 to apply my proposed operation, you first need to pick a bijection between the set of primes and the set of integers. Which bijection are you using? Also, if you define a group structure on the set of all primes, there is no reason why it needs to be closed under the operation on a smaller set, so I don't understand your problem with my solution. If you want to define a group structure on a finite set then I would recommend defining a bijection between that set and the cyclic group of the same order, then your set will inherit the structure of the cyclic group.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Take any bijection between the set of prime and Z which takes 2 to 0 and transport the structure with this bijection.

Comment: Also works with any countable group, such as $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}_0$ or any finite power of a finite or countable group.